# Ошибка поиска jvm.dll

Tags: javafx, jvm

Есть мини программа написана на javafx через Intellij 18.2.5, jdk1.8.0_161 собрана в ехе на win7 x64 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске на win7 x64 никаких проблем хоть с правами хоть без  (тестировал на 2-ух пк)
Hа win10 x64 (тоже 2 пк (на 1 уже была java(131) на другом не было)) ошибка поиска/открытия jvm.dll и путь где должен быть файл, смотрю он там есть и путь правильный. (с последующим сообщением об ошибке запуска jvm)
Так вот что не нравится win10 и как с этим бороться?
 (Дополнение для коментария)
для работы программы не нужна java на пк[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проверьте наличие jmv, набрав Windon + R, cmd, java -version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам спросил сам ответил.
win10 не нравится java 161 помогло обновление на последнюю версию (на текущий момент 191)